# flash simple button with text

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a simple Button in Flash cs5 - as3 called btn1 with a dynamic text called text_txt inside inside it.

The goal is simply to change the text however...

```
btn1.visible=true; // works fine
this.btn1.text_txt.text="hello"; // give a NULL error
```

**My question is: how to programatically change the text that is inside that button ?**

Comment: What class does `btn1` extend? `SimpleButton`? `MovieClip`? `Sprite`? I know you say you have a "simple Button" but the answer depends on what class it extends. Also did you create `btn1` programatically or manually?

Answer (score 4):

Because I have FlashDevelop I can only show you how to do everything programmatically.

If your dealing with a `Sprite` object(which I recommend) then the following is how you access a `TextField` in the `Sprite` object:

```
var textField:TextField = new TextField();
textField.name = "textField";
textField.mouseEnabled = false;

var rectangleShape:Shape = new Shape();
rectangleShape.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
rectangleShape.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 25);
rectangleShape.graphics.endFill();

var buttonSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
buttonSprite.addChild(rectangleShape);
buttonSprite.addChild(textField);
addChild(buttonSprite);

var tf:TextField = TextField(buttonSprite.getChildByName("textField"));
tf.text = "button sprite text";
```

First the `TextField` object called `textField` is instantiated and its `name` property is assigned the string "textField" which is the same as setting its instance name.

Next a `Shape` object called `rectangleShape` is instantiated which is graphically configured to look like a simple red rectangle.

Next a `Sprite` display object object called `buttonSprite` is instantiated and the `textField` and `rectangleShape` display objects are added to it. Then the `Sprite` display object container is added to the stage.

Finally the `buttonSprite` display object container's `getChildByName()` method is called and returns the `textField` display object. To do this the the `textField` display object's name property has to be given as the `getChildByName()` methods's argument. Next the returned `textField` object is stored in a local `TextField` object called `tf` which now gives you access to the `textField`.

**[UPDATE]**

The following is the approach for accessing a `TextField` object via `SimpleButton` object which is similar to accessing it via a `Sprite` object(I don't recommend this though):

```
var textField:TextField = new TextField();
textField.name = "textField";
textField.mouseEnabled = false;

var rectangleShape:Shape = new Shape();
rectangleShape.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
rectangleShape.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 25);
rectangleShape.graphics.endFill();

var simpleButtonSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
simpleButtonSprite.name = "simpleButtonSprite";
simpleButtonSprite.addChild(rectangleShape);
simpleButtonSprite.addChild(textField);

var simpleButton:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton();
simpleButton.upState = simpleButtonSprite;
simpleButton.overState = simpleButtonSprite;
simpleButton.downState = simpleButtonSprite;
simpleButton.hitTestState = simpleButtonSprite;
addChild(simpleButton);

// local simpleButtonSprite object
var sbs:DisplayObjectContainer = DisplayObjectContainer(simpleButton.upState);
//local textField object
var tf:TextField = TextField(sbs.getChildByName("textField"));  
tf.text = "simple button text ";
```

Answer (score 2):

need using basic class MovieClip
btn1 need have 3 frames and text_txt - textField

```
btn1.text_txt.text="blablabla"; // if MovieClip!!!
```

button properties you have that

```
btn1.buttonMode = true;
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, overListener);
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, outListener);
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickListener);

function overListener(e:MouseEvent):void{
 e.currentTarget.gotoAndStop(1)
}
function outListener(e:MouseEvent):void{
 e.currentTarget.gotoAndStop(2)
}
function clickListener(e:MouseEvent):void{
 e.currentTarget.gotoAndStop(3)
}
```

Or you can create `MyBtnClass(_text:String,_MovieClip:MovieClip)` that makes the above.
Sorry my English

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to access the SimpleButton's Children:

For example, in my SimpleButton (named _myButton) at its up State, I have a label (its instance name doesn't matter) and a Sprite (at layer 0):

`var _container:DisplayObjectContainer = DisplayObjectContainer(_myButton.upState);

var _spt:Sprite = Sprite(_container.getChildAt(0));

var _lbl:Label = Label(_container.getChildAt(1));`

**Comments:**
- You can access the diferent button states: upState, downState, hitTestState, overState;
- You can cast to DisplayObjectContainer in order to get the children;
- You cannot use (at least directly) getChildByName because the instance names will be generate dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Add this class in to the button:

```
usage example:
var my_btn_01 : SimpleButtonTf; //add you button instance name here 
write > my_btn_01.text = "ABC"
read  > trace(my_btn_01.text)  //output "ABC"    

package classes {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;

    public class SimpleButtonTf extends SimpleButton {
        private var lbl_up:TextField;
        private var lbl_down:TextField;
        private var lbl_over:TextField;
        public function SimpleButtonTf(){

            //this.super();
            var _container_up:DisplayObjectContainer = DisplayObjectContainer(this.upState);
            var _container_down:DisplayObjectContainer = DisplayObjectContainer(this.downState);
            var _container_over:DisplayObjectContainer = DisplayObjectContainer(this.overState);
            lbl_up = _container_up.getChildAt(1) as TextField;
            lbl_down = _container_down.getChildAt(1) as TextField;
            lbl_over = _container_over.getChildAt(1) as TextField;
        }
        public function set text(str:String):void {

            lbl_up.text = str;
            lbl_down.text = str;
            lbl_over.text = str;
        }

        public function get text():String {

            return lbl_up.text;
        }
    }
}
```